# Is ContentEntityBase::access affected by hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access?

Tags: 8, entities, users

Are calls to the `access()` method on entity objects which is provided by [ContentEntityBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aaccess/8.2.x) affected by [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.2.x)?

I am asking because the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module, in src/ParagraphAccessControllHandler.php, contains the following code.

```
protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $paragraph, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
// Allowed when the operation is not view or the status is true.
/** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
if ($paragraph->getParentEntity() != NULL) {
  // Delete permission on the paragraph, should just depend on 'update'
  // access permissions on the parent.
  $operation = ($operation == 'delete') ? 'update' : $operation;
  $parent_access = $paragraph->getParentEntity()->access($operation, $account, TRUE);
  return AccessResult::allowedIf($operation != 'view' || $paragraph->status->value)
    ->andIf($parent_access);
}
return AccessResult::allowedIf($operation != 'view' || $paragraph->status->value);
}
```

The following hook is in the [Block content permissions](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/joshuaroberson/2849003) module, in block_content_permissions.module.

```
function block_content_permissions_block_content_access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  // Disallow operation access to entity based on user's permissions.
  switch ($operation) {
  case 'delete':
  case 'update':
  // Get block content type.
  $bundle_type = $entity->bundle();
  // Check permissions for block content.
  // Negate to hide operation link.
  return AccessResult::forbiddenIf(!(
    $account->hasPermission('administer block content') &&
    $account->hasPermission("$operation any $bundle_type block content")
    ));
 }
 }
```

By using `kint()`, I can tell that `checkAccess()` is being called, but the hook isn't running. I realize that the block content module is experimental, but theoretically this should work and is in fact working for performing actions on blocks themselves.

Comment: Yes, $entity->access() calls the entity access control handler which usually invokes the hooks. you'll have to provide some more information if something isn't working for you, including your code and so on

Comment: As shown from @Berdir, this is a yes/no question. To make it an acceptable question, you should at least show the code you are using and/or tell us what you find in the documentation that makes you think you misunderstood something.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Question updated with specific examples.

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin user? Because  hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access() is not invoked when you are logged in as admin...

Comment: @Robin I was testing on a non-user-1 account, thanks for the heads up though.